# How to tick-level backtest the spot grid trading strategy?

Tags: python, pandas, back-testing

Is there a Python library with which I could tick-level backtest the famous Spot Grid Trading crypto strategy? I already did the tick data download part from [data.binance.vision](https://data.binance.vision/?prefix=data/spot/daily/trades/), although in my attempt I have used [backtesting.py](https://github.com/kernc/backtesting.py) that seems to not be suitable for tick-level backtests, as discussed [here](https://github.com/kernc/backtesting.py/discussions/566). The grid strategy is pretty straightforward, so I assume it should be fairly easy to backtest on tick-level. I assume there are others who have already achieved this, I just can't find it, so that's why I'm asking the question.

The strategy is described [here](https://www.binance.com/en/support/faq/d5f441e8ab544a5b98241e00efb3a4ab) and I also found a few open source references on GitHub:

- https://github.com/xzmeng/crypto-grid-backtest/blob/master/grid/backtest.py
- https://github.com/webclinic017/aibitgo/blob/master/strategy/GridStrategyPercent.py
- https://github.com/ulbdir/trading_bot/blob/main/GridStrategy.py

### What I have so far

```py
from backtesting import Backtest
from grid.grid import GridStrategy
from tick_data.data import Kind, load_data

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # 1s interval pickle
    df = load_data(symbol="ETHUSDT", start="2022-12-16", end="2022-12-16", kind=Kind.SPOT, tz="UTC")

    df = df.resample("1s").first().dropna()
    print(f'{df}')

    # Backtest
    bt = Backtest(df, GridStrategy, cash=10_000, commission=.001, exclusive_orders=True)
    stats = bt.run()
    bt.plot()
```

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from enum import Enum
from backtesting import Strategy


class GridType(Enum):
    ARITHMETIC = 1
    GEOMETRIC = 2


class GridStrategy(Strategy):
    lower_limit = 2000
    upper_limit = 10000
    grid_count = 4
    grid_type = GridType.ARITHMETIC
    grids = []

    current_position = None

    def init(self):
        self.grids = self.get_grids(self.lower_limit, self.upper_limit, self.grid_count, self.grid_type)

        print(f'{self.grids}')

    def next(self):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def get_grids(lower_limit, upper_limit, grid_count, grid_type=GridType.ARITHMETIC):
        if grid_type == GridType.ARITHMETIC:
            grids = np.linspace(lower_limit, upper_limit, grid_count + 1)
        elif grid_type == GridType.GEOMETRIC:
            grids = np.geomspace(lower_limit, upper_limit, grid_count + 1)
        else:
            print("not right range type")
        return grids
```

```py
import io
import logging
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from datetime import date
from enum import Enum
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Optional, Union
from zipfile import ZipFile
from datetime import datetime

import pandas as pd
import httpx
from pandas import DataFrame

DATA_DIR = Path.cwd().joinpath("data")


def create_logger():
    logger_ = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger_.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    formatter = logging.Formatter(
        "%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"
    )
    handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger_.addHandler(handler)
    return logger_


logger = create_logger()


class Kind(Enum):
    SPOT = "spot"
    FUTURES_UM = "futures/um"
    FUTURES_CM = "futures/cm"


class DataLoader:
    def __init__(
            self,
            kind: Kind,
            symbol: str,
            start: Union[date, str],
            end: Union[date, str],
            tz: str = None,
    ) -> None:
        self.kind = kind
        self.symbol = symbol
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
        self.tz = tz

    def load_data(self) -> pd.DataFrame:
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=20) as executor:
            dfs = list(
                executor.map(self.load_daily_data, pd.date_range(self.start, self.end))
            )
        df = pd.concat(dfs)
        if self.tz:
            df.index = df.index.tz_localize("utc").tz_convert(self.tz)
        return df

    def load_daily_data(self, dt: date) -> Optional[pd.DataFrame]:
        try:
            return self.load_local_daily_data(dt)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            return self.download_daily_data(dt)

    def load_local_daily_data(self, dt: date) -> pd.DataFrame:
        pickle_path = self.get_daily_pickle_path(dt)
        return pd.read_pickle(pickle_path)

    def download_daily_data(self, dt: date) -> Optional[pd.DataFrame]:
        logger.info(f'Downloading {self.symbol} {datetime.strftime(dt, "%Y-%m-%d")}')
        url = f'https://data.binance.vision/data/{self.kind.value}/daily/trades/{self.symbol}/' \
              f'{self.symbol}-trades-{datetime.strftime(dt, "%Y-%m-%d")}.zip'

        resp = httpx.get(url)
        resp.raise_for_status()

        with ZipFile(io.BytesIO(resp.content)) as zf:
            with zf.open(zf.namelist()[0]) as f:
                df = pd.read_csv(f, usecols=[1, 4], names=["price", "datetime"])

        df["datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(df.datetime, unit="ms")
        df.set_index("datetime", inplace=True)
        # df = df.resample("1s").first().dropna()

        # df.price.resample("1s").agg({
        #     "Open": "first",
        #     "High": "max",
        #     "Low": "min",
        #     "Close": "last"
        # })

        pkl_path = self.get_daily_pickle_path(dt)
        Path(pkl_path).parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
        df.to_pickle(pkl_path)

        return df

    def get_daily_pickle_path(self, dt: date) -> Path:
        return DATA_DIR.joinpath(self.kind.value, f"{self.symbol}-{dt.year}-{dt.month}-{dt.day}.pkl")


def load_data(
        symbol: str,
        start: Union[date, str],
        end: Union[date, str] = date.today(),
        kind: Union[Kind, str] = Kind.SPOT,
        tz: str = "UTC",
) -> DataFrame:
    if isinstance(kind, str):
        kind = {"spot": Kind.SPOT, "cm": Kind.FUTURES_CM, "um": Kind.FUTURES_UM}[kind]
    return DataLoader(kind, symbol, start, end, tz).load_data()
```